# How to delay react bubble sort in react using useState?

Tags: reactjs, time, react-hooks, sleep, bubble-sort

I want to delay this bubble sort algorithm. I am using reacts `useState` inside. after each swap I want the func to be delayed. how can you do this?

```javascript
const  sortDivs =    () => {
    var newArr = [...randomHeights]
    for (let i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < newArr.length - i; j++) {
            if(newArr[j].height > newArr[j+1]?.height) {
                let tmp = newArr[j];
                newArr[j] = newArr[j + 1]
                newArr[j + 1] = tmp;
                setRandomHeights(newArr)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `delayed`? So it runs after some time?

Comment: yeah right, just like sleep(time)

Answer (score 0):

read about ' setTimeout ' it would be helpful.

[setTimeout](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/settimeout-in-react-components-using-hooks)

Comment: i know that, but it did not work with setTimeout + useState in that case